# swift get current vpn connection

Tags: ios, swift, vpn

I'm using a an app called "VyprVPN" to log in to an VPN. I now want to write my own app, where I want to know if the phone is connected to a VPN or not. And the server address and username if possible.
Can I do that?
I've tried this:

```
    let manager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager()
    let connection = manager.connection;
    if let prot = manager.protocolConfiguration{
        print(prot.username)
    }else{
        print("no protocol")
    }
```

But it will say "no protocol" although I'm connected